# OOPHP suitable alternative to singleton pattern?

Tags: php, singleton

I'm currently working on an oophp application. I have a site class which will contain all of the configuration settings for the app. Originally, I was going to use the singleton pattern to allow each object to reference a single instance of the site object, however mainly due to testing issues involved in this pattern, I've decided to try a different approach.

I would like to make the site class the main parent class in my app and call it's constructor from within the constructors of the child classes, in order to make all the properties available whenever needed.

When run for the first time, the class will only contain the db details for the app. To get the remaining values a query must be performed using the db details.  However, any subsequent instances will be clones of the original (with all values). I may also set a Boolean flag to perform the query again a completely new instance is required.

Would this be a viable alternative to the singleton and would it solve the testing issues it causes? This is all theory atm, I haven't started to code anything yet,

Any thoughts or advice greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 having the same issue very often. Very interested to hear what will arise here.

Comment: What are the testing issues you encounter with a singleton?

Comment: The technique does not work well with loose coupling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way is to have an 'configuration' object that will get passed to the constructors of all your other classes. So, almost something like a singleton, except it's explicitly created and passed only to classes that need it. This approach is usually called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 2):

After trying many different techniques, what I have found functional and reliable is this method:

Use a bootstrap, or initialization file. It is located in the ROOT of the site with the proper permission and safe-guards against direct access.

All pages in the site first include this file. Within it, I create all my global objects (settings, user), and reference them from there.

For example:

```
// OBJECT CREATION
$Config = new Configuration();
$User = new User();
```

Then within classes that require these objects:

```
public function __construct($id = NULL) {
    global $Config; // DEPENDENCY INJECTION SOUNDS LIKE AN ADDICTION!

    if($Config->allow_something) {
        $this->can_do_something = true;
    }

    if(NULL !== $id) {
        $this->load_record($id);
    }
}
```

Notice that I just access these global objects from within the class, and how I don't have to include the object variables as the first constructor parameter each and every time. That gets old.

Also, having a static Database class has been very helpful. There are no objects I have to worry about passing, I can just call `$row = DB::select_row($sql_statement);`; check out the PhpConsole class.

UPDATE
Thanks for the upvote, whoever did that. It has called attention to the fact that my answer is not something I am proud of. While it might help the OP accomplish what they wanted, it is NOT a good practice.

Passing objects to new object constructors is a good practice (dependency injection), and while "inconvenient," as with other things in life, the extra effort is worth it.

The only redeeming part of my answer is use of the facade pattern (eg. DB::select_row()). This is not necessarily a singleton (something the OP wanted to avoid), and gives you an opportunity to present a slimmed down interface.

Laravel is a modern PHP framework that uses dependency injection and facades, among other proven design patterns. I suggest that any novice developer review these and other such design practices thoroughly.